# Is it possible to restrict the type of field for a Java annotation?

Tags: java, eclipse, types, annotations

It's possible to restrict an Java annotation to fields, methods, etc.

But, how about a field or a method name or type?

For, example, I would like to create an annotation that can be put only in fields of the type *long* and with name *id*;

Comment: There are annotation processors you can run at compile time to check this. I suspect it is not worth the effort.

Comment: I tried it. I created a library with some annotations and a processor. After I imported the library to the project, added a annotation to a class field and added the .jar to the project Factory Path in Eclipse. The anotations should show some error messages, but nothing happens.

Comment: You can change the compilation this way, but I suspect this doesn't change eclipse.  If you want eclipse to change it's warnings/errors you need to add a plugin for it.

Comment: The tutorials that I read do not talk nothing about plugins for Eclipse. Just about the steps that I said. It must work without plugin, I think.

Comment: Thanks! The processor is now working. The problem was an compilation error related to Build Path. No need of a plugin for it. At last not what I understand was a plugin. Actually I only created a .jar with the annotations, the processor and the configurations and added it to Eclipse Annotation Processing Factory Path on the project in which I want the errors and warning and make some little more configurations.

Comment: @user, please post your (own) solution as a real answer and them mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It possible using an [Annotation Processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).

Some tutorials that may help in this task:

http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/

http://java.dzone.com/news/using-java-6-processors